# How do I take user inputs in class. Python

Tags: python-3.x

I tried input() but it felt and was wrong. Instead of me having to type print(dog1.name), I need a way of taking inputs from user. For eg- If user inputs dog1, all his attributes show up. I learned python in a messed up way so I understand OOP a lil and classes but can't find a way to do this or google it since I don't know the terminologies or what exactly to search.
PS : Can anyone tell me how could've I googled it?? Thankyou for your time :)

```
class Dog:
def __init__(self, name, breed, color, age):
    self.name = name
    self.breed = breed
    self.color = color
    self.age = age

dog1 = Dog('Jim', 'Shep', 'Brown', 6)
dog2 = Dog('Jimmy', 'Lab', 'Black', 5)
dog3 = Dog('Jimo', 'Dane', 'Black', 3)

print(dog1.name)
```

Comment: Look into python dictionaries. They are way to map names/strings to any object. For example, `my_dict = {'dog1': dog1, 'dog2': dog2, 'dog3': dog3 }` would allow you to later reference the object like this. `which_dog = input('Input a dog: ')` `print(my_dict[which_dog].name)`.

Comment: Asking user to enter name of the objects, makes no sense. You don't want any random person to know about variables(object names in this case) that you're using.

Answer (score 1):

class Person:
def **init**(self, firstname, lastname):
self.firstname = firstname
self.lastname = lastname

```
 @classmethod
 def get_user_input(self):
     while 1:
         try:
             firstname = input('Enter first name: ')
             lastname = input('Enter last name')
             return self(firstname,lastname)
         except:
             print('Invalid input!')
             continue
```

person3.show_full_name()

Answer (score 1):

Check this out!

```
class Dog:
   global x 
   x = input(" Dog: ")
   def __init__(self, name, breed, color, age):
       self.name = name
       self.breed = breed
       self.color = color
       self.age = age
def askUser():
    if (x == "dog1"):
        print (f"Name: {dog1.name}")
        print(f"Breed: {dog1.breed}")
        print(f"Color: {dog1.color}")
        print(f"Age: {dog1.age}")
    elif (x == "dog2"):
        print(f"Name: {dog2.name}")
        print(f"Breed: {dog2.breed}")
        print(f"Color: {dog2.color}")
        print(f"Age: {dog2.age}")
    elif (x == "dog3"):
        print(f"Name: {dog3.name}")
        print(f"Breed: {dog3.breed}")
        print(f"Color: {dog3.color}")
        print(f"Age: {dog3.age}")
    else:
        print("No match")
dog1 = Dog('Jim', 'Shep', 'Brown', 6)
dog2 = Dog('Jimmy', 'Lab', 'Black', 5)
dog3 = Dog('Jimo', 'Dane', 'Black', 3)
askUser()
```